# mysql with join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

**i have a 3 tables in mysql **

1- Client Table

```
 PK
```

| NUM_CLIENT | NAME_CLIENT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ALEX |
| 2 | ADAM |

2- Invoice Table

```
  FK
```

| NUM_CLIENT_INV | INV_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 1 | 2000 |

3- Sales returns Table

```
  FK
```

| NUM_CLIENT_SR | Return_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 |
| 1 | 400 |

my query is

```
SELECT  NAME_CLIENT , NUM_CLIENT , INV_VALUE , Return_VALUE  FROM client

             LEFT JOIN Invoice 
             ON NUM_CLIENT_INV = NUM_CLIENT 
             
             LEFT JOIN Sales returns
             ON NUM_CLIENT_SR = NUM_CLIENT
```

The expected result is :

| NAME_CLIENT | NUM_CLIENT | INV_VALUE | Return_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALEX | 1 | 1000 | null |
| ALEX | 1 | null | 300 |
| ALEX | 1 | 2000 | null |
| ALEX | 1 | null | 400 |
| ADAM | 2 | null | null |

but the result was given is :

| NAME_CLIENT | NUM_CLIENT | INV_VALUE | Return_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALEX | 1 | 1000 | 300 |
| ALEX | 1 | 1000 | 400 |
| ALEX | 1 | 2000 | 300 |
| ALEX | 1 | 2000 | 400 |
| ADAM | 2 | null | null |

there is duplicate in result in columns INV_VALUE and Return_VALUE

What Is The Right Query That Give Me The expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

Your existing joins return all combinations of client, optional invoice, and optional sales rows for each client.

If you want invoices and sales on separate rows, you need to join them in separate queries and union those queries.  Use an inner joins so that if there are neither sales nor invoices you don't get two null/null rows, but then you have to add an extra query to get the null/null row when there are neither.

```
SELECT  NAME_CLIENT , NUM_CLIENT , INV_VALUE , NULL as Return_VALUE  FROM client
INNER JOIN Invoice
    ON NUM_CLIENT_INV = NUM_CLIENT 
UNION ALL
SELECT  NAME_CLIENT , NUM_CLIENT , NULL , Return_VALUE  FROM client
INNER JOIN Sales returns
    ON NUM_CLIENT_SR = NUM_CLIENT 
UNION ALL
SELECT  NAME_CLIENT , NUM_CLIENT , NULL , NULL  FROM client
LEFT JOIN Invoice
    ON NUM_CLIENT_INV = NUM_CLIENT 
LEFT JOIN Sales returns
    ON NUM_CLIENT_SR = NUM_CLIENT 
WHERE NUM_CLIENT_INV IS NULL AND NUM_CLIENT_SR IS NULL
ORDER BY NUM_CLIENT
```

Comment: there is an error  in your query (Unknown column 'Return_VALUE' in 'field list')   because this coulmn dosnt belong to first jion

Comment: sorry, I fixed that